# Add multiple conditions with "if" where we compare all the conditions and only print failed at the end

Tags: python, list, compare

I have two lists which I extracted from two different paths and created a list:

```
list1 = ["123", "", "6/6/2020", "testing"]
list2 = ["6/6/2020", "testing", "hello"]
```

I need to compare `if list1[2] == list2[0] and list1[3] == list2[1] and list1[1] == list2[2]`
I want the comparison to be done on all the above conditions and only print at the end which Comparision failed. So that the user knows which value is not matching.
At the end I want to print "value of {list2[2]} does not match". **How to add multiple conditions with "if" where we compare all the conditions and only print at the end which condition failed in python code?** Please help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you asking how to write ifs in Python?

Comment: You've written the comparison you need already, what are you asking for exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear and I am missing your own code for this. Would you need to compare all items in list1 with all items in list2? In that case it sounds like the job for a double for loop.

```
for each i in list1:
    for each j in list2:
        if list1[i] == list2[j]:
            do something
```

I will not write the code for you since this is such basic code.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. Not what I was looking for, I have edited the question to make it more clear. How to add multiple "if" conditions where we compare all the conditions and only print at the end which condition failed in python code?

Comment: @bhavi it is still not clear to me what you want from the program? Could you provide more examples AND an example output for each use case?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question you want to output which value of `list1` doesn't match. You're a bit unclear in the question about that.

You have

```
list1 = ["123", "", "6/6/2020", "testing"]
list2 = ["6/6/2020", "testing", "hello"]
```

Now transform `list2` so that it matches the structure of `list1`.

```
list2 = [list1[0]] + [list2[2]] + list2[:2]
```

This will give you `['123', 'hello', '6/6/2020', 'testing']` for `list2`. Now comparing and printing a message for the non-match is easy:

```
for i, values in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
    if values[0] != values[1]:
        print(f'list[{i}] does not match')
```

Result: `list[1] does not match`.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. Not what I was looking for, I have edited the question to make it more clear.